# What does <py3fix> mean?

Tags: python, compilation, bottle

I am reading the *bottle* source code and see:

```
eval(compile('def _raise(*a): raise a[0], a[1], a[2]', '<py3fix>', 'exec'))
```

I read the documentation about `compile` and it only tells me that `<string>` is commonly used. I also googled and searched on stackoverflow but can not find the related info.

So can anyone tell me how `<py3fix>` affects compilation? And is there any other filename, where can I find the related documentation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't affect it at all. It's just a name that it's used to identify where the compiled code is coming from, so you can use string you want.

Like the docs say:

> compile(source, filename, mode[, flags[, dont_inherit]])
>
> The filename argument should give the file from which the code was
>   read;  pass some recognizable value if it wasn’t read from a file
>   ('< string>' is commonly used).

in the case where the `source` is not being read from a file (like here) they suggest that you use `<string>` so that you know that this code is compiled from a written string.

---

The person who comited the code, did it when fixing some [Bottle Python 2/3 bugs](https://github.com/defnull/bottle/commit/166251bb6288d63c4faf5e7cfcf63312014ec8d1). So I'm guessing that he used `<py3fix>` as a way to identify the assertion was raised from the `def _raise` he compiles when the user is running 2.x:

```
>>> eval(compile('def _raise(*a): raise a[0], a[1], a[2]', '<py3fix>', 'exec'))
>>> _raise(Exception, "error message", None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<py3fix>", line 1, in _raise
Exception: error message

>>> eval(compile('def _raise(*a): raise a[0], a[1], a[2]', '<my_source_file>', 'exec'))
>>> _raise(Exception, "error message", None)Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<my_source_file>", line 1, in _raise
Exception: error message
```

Comment: Sort of. It's a comment about *where* it came from, so it shouldn't be too verbose.